# An application of Nash's embedding theorem to manifolds with fixed volume form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have a smooth (possibly compact, or closed, or oriented, or more than one of the previous) $n$-manifold $M$ together with a fixed volume form $\rho\in\Omega^n(M)$. Can $M$ be embedded into some Euclidean space in such a way that the volume form is sent to the restriction of the standard Euclidean volume form to $M$?

Formally, I am looking for an embedding $i:M\to\mathbb{R}^N$ (for some integer $N$) such that
$$i^*d\operatorname{vol}_{\mathbb{R}^N} = \rho,$$
where $d\operatorname{vol}_{\mathbb{R}^N}=dx^1\wedge\ldots\wedge dx^N$ is the usual volume form.

---

A positive answer would follow from Nash's embedding theorem provided we can equip $M$ with a Riemannian metric inducing $\rho$ as volume form.

Comment: Does this question answer your question (see the comment by Otis Chodosh):
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/60554/measures-on-riemannian-manifolds-which-are-not-induced-by-the-volume-form-of-som

Comment: @PhillipAndreae More or less. I'll write my solution to the question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a smooth $n$-manifold with a fixed volume form $\rho$. Equip it with a Riemannian metric $g$ (which exists for example by taking the pullback of the standard metric on Euclidean space after embedding $M$ by Whitney's theorem), and denote by $*_g$ the Hodge-$*$ operator with respect to $g$. If $\mu\in C^\infty(M)$ is everywhere strictly positive we have
$$*_{\mu g} = \mu^{\frac{n}{2}-p}*_g$$
on $p$-forms. The volume form induced by $g$ is given by $*_g1$, thus we look at the equation
$$1 = *_{\mu g}\rho=\mu^{-\frac{n}{2}}*_g\rho.$$
This is solved by setting $\mu = (*_g\rho)^{\frac{2}{n}}$, showing that in fact every conformal class on $M$ has a representative inducing the desired volume form as its volume form.